# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, viewmodel

I am using SimpleMVVM and while editing an object, SimpleMVVM creates a new Model object and a Copy object.   The original Model object is cloned to the Copy object using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.

Here is the actual code:

```
        Copy = Model.Clone();
```

...

```
        public static T Clone<T>(this T obj)
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
            };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, settings);
            return result;
        }
```

I am having an issue when the Clone method tries to Deserialize a DataView.  The error is:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

I am not sure how to handle this error as the only thing happening to cause the error is a retrieval (get) of this property:

```
/// <summary>
/// Dataview of SQL Results Table
/// </summary>
[XmlIgnore]
public DataView TableDataView
{
    get 
    {
        return _TableDataView;                
    }
    set
    {
        _TableDataView = value;

        // Add listener for changes to the TableDataView
        _TableDataView.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(TableDataViewChanged);

        TableDataViewIsDirty = false;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.TableDataView);
    }
}
private DataView _TableDataView = new DataView();
```

Is there some issue with trying to deserialize a DataView using JSON and if so is there a way around it?  Alternatively, is there a way to specify that a property (TableDataView) NOT be included in the Serialize\Deserialize process (something like the [XmlIgnore] flag)?

Comment: To prevent the `DataTableView` property from being serialized, you can apply the [`[JsonIgnore]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) attribute; it does the same thing as `[XmlIgnore]`.  As for actually serializing it, that looks quite difficult.

Comment: @dbc Thank you, that solved the problem.  If you enter it as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the `DataTableView` property from being serialized, you can apply the [`[JsonIgnore]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) attribute; it does the same thing for Json.NET as [`[XmlIgnore]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does for `XmlSerializer`.